# Apache crashing every day

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

The Apache server is crashing everyday. When I checked the crash report from /var/crash/ it looks as below :

```
ProblemType: Crash
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/sbin/apache2
ExecutableTimestamp: 1468596976
ProcCmdline: /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ProcCwd: /etc/apache2
ProcEnviron:
PATH=(custom, no user)
LANG=C
```

The apache and other package updates has not been updated since a long time. Will upgrading the package fix this issue?

I am not aware of how to fix this problem and this happens every night. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had those kind of crash, but fact is they could come from dozens of different causes and you could add all the information of the world it would be hard to help. But at least you could put a little effort and add apache version configuration of your site, extract of access log when apache crashes  ... in your site config or apache config add the time of the request by tunning log format and add `%D` you might notice that at the moment of the crash a page is called and took forever to be generated crashing your server. Good luck.

Comment: You may have some infos in /var/log/syslog

Comment: I will add more information as mentioned. Thanks